# Unshift Not Working in a Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have to add an item to my array through a function, but the code I made is *not* adding my item (orignalFlavors is my array).

```
function addFlavor(originalFlavors) {
  originalFlavors.unshift("Rainbow Sherbert");
}
console.log(originalFlavors)
```

Comment: Did you actually _call_ the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function `addFlavor` as well:

```
let originalFlavors = [...];
function addFlavor(originalFlavors) {
  originalFlavors.unshift("Rainbow Sherbert");
}
addFlavor(originalFlavors);
console.log(originalFlavors);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I cannot believe I overlooked that for as long as I did.  You are a life saver!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're defining the array, and then calling the function:

```
let originalFlavors = []
function addFlavor(of) { // use a different name to avoid shadowing and confusion
  of.unshift("Rainbow Sherbert");
  return of;
}
originalFlavors = addFlavor(originalFlavors);
console.log(originalFlavors);
```

Comment: @FinnLyonn Works fine for me. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords, https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words, https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words